# 403 Error when using Axios to post to Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios

I am using a Django server connected to a React Native front end.

The server works fine in my browser, but I get an error when trying to post in my app from Axios. I get the following error:

```
[26/Aug/2021 13:26:53] "POST /api/ticket/ HTTP/1.1" 403 58
Forbidden: /api/ticket/
```

Here is my **axios** function:

```
const getTicket = async function () {
  try {
    let res = await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ticket/", {
      userID: 5,
      eventID: 1,
    });
    return res;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return err;
  }
};
```

Here is my **models.py** for the Ticket class:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    ticketID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    userID = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    eventID = models.ForeignKey(
        Event, related_name='tickets', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bookedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ticketID)
```

Here is my TicketSerializer in **serializers.py**:

```
class TicketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = "__all__"
```

My **views.py**

```
class TicketViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Ticket.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TicketSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]


class MyTicketViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Ticket.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TicketSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Ticket.objects.filter(userID=user)
```

My **urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('ticket', TicketViewSet)
router.register('myticket', MyTicketViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

What is confusing me is that more complex axios calls are working, such as this one below which correctly identifies the userid from the axios call alone:

```
const getMyTickets = async function () {
  try {
    let res = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/myticket/");
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return err;
  }
};
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be a life saver!

Comment: I had a very similar problem yesterday. And this post solved the problem: https://medium.com/@emeruchecole9/uploading-images-to-rest-api-backend-in-react-js-b931376b5833

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately this doesn't quite solve the problem sorry!